# Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]

Tags: magento-1.9, error, xml, ce-1.9.1.1

I get the following repeated a lot in magento 1.9.1.1 system.log. any ideas?

```
2015-05-17T09:17:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: &lt;/layout&gt;  in /home/x/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 28961

2015-05-17T09:17:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:  ^  in /home/x/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 28961
```

_default code

```
        // custom local layout updates file - load always last
        $updateFiles[] = 'local.xml';
        $layoutStr = '';
        foreach ($updateFiles as $file) {
            $filename = $design->getLayoutFilename($file, array(
                '_area'    => $area,
                '_package' => $package,
                '_theme'   => $theme
            ));
            if (!is_readable($filename)) {
                continue;
            }
            $fileStr = file_get_contents($filename);
            $fileStr = str_replace($this->_subst['from'], $this->_subst['to'], $fileStr);
            $fileXml = simplexml_load_string($fileStr, $elementClass);
            if (!$fileXml instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
                continue;
            }
            $layoutStr .= $fileXml->innerXml();
        }
        $layoutXml = simplexml_load_string('<layouts>'.$layoutStr.'</layouts>', $elementClass);
        return $layoutXml;
    }
}
```

My local XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links">
<remove name="return_link"/>           
 <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" /></action>
           <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" /></action>
    </reference>
<checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="checkout.cart">
                <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
  <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="checkout.cart">
                <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.additional">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
 </default>  
</layout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of your XML files is broken, use this command to find it:

```
cd /your/magento/root/dir
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -exec xmllint --noout {} \;
```

(I hope your on a *nix)

Comment: You will find using Linux for development and xmllint are your best buds when tracking down broken xml files... Same goes for Mac, as OS X is a *nix variant.

Comment: I got tons of these finds

./app/code/core/Mage/Tag/etc/wsi.xml:2: namespace error : xmlns:typens: 'urn:{{var wsdl.name}}' is not a valid URI
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
                                                      ^
./app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/wsdl.xml:2: namespace error : xmlns:typens: 'urn:{{var wsdl.name}}' is not a valid URI
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2

./app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/etc/wsi.xml:2: namespace error : xmlns:typens: 'urn:{{var wsdl.name}}' is not a valid URI
<wsdl:def

etc

Comment: these are ok :) namespace errors can be ignores

Comment: But there should be something about one of the layout xml files

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt thanks for your answer, above gives `./core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml:2: namespace error : xmlns:typens: 'urn:{{var wsdl.name}}' is not a valid URI
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2` any idea about this?

Comment: This is fine, magento will replace the `{{var wsdl.name}}` part

Comment: I am trying to find broken xml but can't find it -----  find: xmllint: No such file or directory

Comment: It seems you used a directory (.) which doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the real problem, but your `local.xml` looks a bit weird. Try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <remove name="return_link"/>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
                <url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl"/>
            </action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
                <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl"/>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
        <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
    </checkout_cart_index>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.additional">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>product_tag_list</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Besides of that, make sure that there are no invalid XML files. Therefore, use an unchanged default theme and try to disable all third party extensions.

Comment: Nope, still same

Comment: As said, then you can check if it also happens with a standard theme and if it still occurs, disable each extension and see if that helps.