# system.log so many problem. update.php,Autoload.php error

Tags: php, extensions, error, magento-1.9.2.0

so many have a problem... 
from the system.log
what problem ..  ?
i'm try delete 'ves_pdfpro' but not a resolve.
please an intelligible explanation

```
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:41:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T03:41:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T03:41:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T05:35:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T05:35:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T05:35:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-30T14:30:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 161
```

this is update.php 450 line

```
        // custom local layout updates file - load always last
        $updateFiles[] = 'local.xml';
        $layoutStr = '';
        foreach ($updateFiles as $file) {
            $filename = $design->getLayoutFilename($file, array(
                '_area'    => $area,
                '_package' => $package,
                '_theme'   => $theme
            ));
            if (!is_readable($filename)) {
                continue;
            }
            $fileStr = file_get_contents($filename);
            $fileStr = str_replace($this->_subst['from'], $this->_subst['to'], $fileStr);
            $fileXml = simplexml_load_string($fileStr, $elementClass);
            if (!$fileXml instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
                continue;
            }
            $layoutStr .= $fileXml->innerXml();
        }
        $layoutXml = simplexml_load_string('<layouts>'.$layoutStr.'</layouts>', $elementClass);
        return $layoutXml;
    }
}
```

and this is Autoload.php line 161

```
/**
 * Save information about used classes per scope with class popularity
 * Class_Name:popularity
 *
 * @return Varien_Autoload
 */
protected function _saveCollectedStat()
{
    if (!is_dir($this->_collectPath)) {
        @mkdir($this->_collectPath);
        @chmod($this->_collectPath, 0777);
    }

    if (!is_writeable($this->_collectPath)) {
        return $this;
    }

    foreach ($this->_arrLoadedClasses as $scope => $classes) {
        $file = $this->_collectPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$scope.'.csv';
        $data = array();
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $data = explode("\n", file_get_contents($file));
            foreach ($data as $index => $class) {
                $class = explode(':', $class);
                $searchIndex = array_search($class[0], $classes);
                if ($searchIndex !== false) {
                    $class[1]+=1;
                    unset($classes[$searchIndex]);
                }
                $data[$index] = $class[0].':'.$class[1];
            }
        }
        foreach ($classes as $class) {
            $data[] = $class . ':1';
        }
        file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $data));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You deleted VES_PdfPro, so the files are no longer found. You need to clear your cache, so the config is reread to make sure the observer are no longer used.

[And to find the broken XML file you can use xmllint](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68168/warning-simplexml-load-string-a-href-function-simplexml-load-stringfunct/74945#74945)

Comment: i don't know this solution...(T.T)