# not working mage::log

Tags: error, magento-1.9.2.0

```
Mage::log(print_r($filename, true));
```

is not working in Update.php..
and my homepage cpu100% .... what problem?

```
2016-02-03T04:11:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-03T04:11:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-03T07:32:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-03T07:32:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-03T07:32:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-02-03T10:22:35+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: filename  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 460
2016-02-03T10:22:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): 
2016-02-03T10:22:49+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: filename  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 460
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/74945/17176

try that out

Comment: @LukeRodgers i'm try "cd /your/magento/root/dir " but i don't knwo 'your','root' what is this ?

Comment: @LukeRodgers not working in my console cd /your/magento/root/dir
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -exec xmllint --noout {} \;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing your error log it looks like it is working. The row:

```
2016-02-03T10:22:35+00:00 DEBUG (7):
```

Would appear to be your log, i.e. it's empty. If you look at the row before:

```
2016-02-03T10:22:35+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: filename  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 460
```

We can see that you are getting an error due to undefined variable `filename`, which is the variable you are attempting to write to the log file. The call to print_r will therefore return an empty string. I'm assuming therefore that your `Mage::log` call is on line 460 of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php`.

Comment: i want 'simplexml_load_string'error way of solution..plz tell me !