# Getting error if xml settings are loaded from cache

Tags: magento-1.9, error, configuration

I am getting the captured error log as below

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ><useccv>0</useccv><min_order_total/><max_order_total/><sort_order/><min_order_t  in D:\wamp\www\premo_core\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 384

I am not sure which of my changes produced this error because I am getting this error since last one month? So I am unable to find which config file has error.

**Edit:**

I am trying to debug it by myself and below is my observation.

1. I am just cleaning the cache folder and refresh the home page on my 
   browser. At this time I have no parse error in system.log
2. Without clearing the cache folder again I am refreshing the page. At this time above said error is being captured.

From the above observation I understood that there is a problem while loading the configuration from cache.

In `\lib\Varien\Simplexml\config.xml` configuration file under `loadCache()` method I made changes as below

```
public function loadCache()
    {
        if (!$this->validateCacheChecksum()) {
            return false;
        }

        /*$xmlString = $this->_loadCache($this->getCacheId());
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString, $this->_elementClass);
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($xml);die;
        if ($xml) {
            $this->_xml = $xml;
            $this->setCacheSaved(true);
            return true;
        }*/

        return false;
    }
```

Means, I just restricted to load from `cache` just reading the config file every time. Now I am not getting the error. But loading time increased since every time it read all file.

Also, I referred [Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68168/warning-simplexml-load-string-a-href-function-simplexml-load-stringfunct) and tried trouble shoot.

I got below error

> /core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml:2: namespace error : xmlns:typens:
>   'urn:{{var wsdl.name}}' is not a valid URI

Can someone suggest now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer for my question.

I have a custom payment gateway. One of it config value has been saved in `core_config_data` table with a special character as `~`. I am not sure how did the character came into th `path` field in `core_config_data` table.

After I deleted the record manually error has gone away.

At last, this is my first question I didn't get ant relevant answer from community.

Answer (score 1):

You have using  any 3rd party payment gateways which is create this issue.

You need to check at  ***config.xml files of all  3rd extensions***.In those config.xml files , have a syntax issue  at code `<useccv>0</useccv><min_order_total/>`you need to fix that.

Comment: Thats what I am wondering too, When I search throughout the folder on my local and community code pool, I cant find anything like this

Comment: then may at core modules

Comment: I never change any core file, Anyway I will check it once,

Comment: I checked it once again, But I cant find anything. Is there a way to find which modules xml file has issue?

Comment: Also check at system. Xml

Comment: By referring http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68168/warning-simplexml-load-string-a-href-function-simplexml-load-stringfunct I ran the same on my server I got like `./core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml:2: namespace error : xmlns:typens: 'urn:{{var wsdl.name}}' is not a valid URI
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2` any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The Linux OS environment has a developer tool, `xmllint` that can be used to find issues like this. Strain the `.xml` files you've modified through it and it finds this stuff really quickly.

Check to see if there are Gnu or .git tools available for Windows that will port this over to your development environment or test on your live Linux Staging server.